# Azure DataFactory Unable to connect to On prem DataBase Using Private Link

Tags: sql-server, azure-data-factory, oracle-adf

I am trying to connect Azure Data Factory to Database using SHIR hosted on-prem machine. The machine does not have any internet connectivity and also port 443 is not opened for any additional connectivity like *.servicebus.windows.net  443 Required by the self-hosted IR for interactive authoring.
We are following the link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-private-link
The Private link has been created as per the steps mentioned in the above link.
The shir connectivity is Running with Limited as described in the document.

When I am trying to connect the database using the integration runtime the connection could not be made and I am getting the following error.

The database is accessible from the on-prem machine and is tested

Does anyone have insights how to handle it without opening the 443 port on the On- prem Machine?
[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJlxF.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAhJ2.png)

We have used the following document
We are following the link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-private-link.
Connectivity is working with On Prem.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VHW6.png)